# Avoiding merge conflicts with git

Tags: git, merge

I've been using git for a while, and I understand why merge conflicts happen and that I need to make the final decision between two conflicting blocks of code.

However, I want to find a way to fix merge conflicts without git modifying the conflicting files.  For example, if there are merge conflicts in a Django template or HTML file when I pull from dev into prod, the conflict lines go live on my site.

In most cases, merging is not actually what I want for a lot of HTML content I have.  I usually prefer only one version of the two conflicting files.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, if there are merge conflicts in a Django template or HTML file when I pull from dev into prod, the conflict lines go live on my site.

Why would merge occur in production? Don't do that.
If you ever considered doing it, merge using a new branch, then **push** to production.

> In most cases, merging is not actually what I want for a lot of HTML content I have. I usually prefer only one version of the two conflicting files.

To overwrite files/directories on your local copy, use:

`git checkout <from_branch> <path1> <path2> ...`.

Comment: Thanks.  I know about git checkout but doing that as a substitute for git pull seems like a pain.  I'll try messing around with new branches for a merge.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) on your production server with the `--ff-only` flag? That would ensure that you've already made the new changes apply cleanly on top of whatever your production server already has.